# Unable to print debug messages in sicslowmac.c

Tags: c, contiki

I have set `#define DEBUG 1` in [sicslowmac.c](https://github.com/contiki-os/contiki/blob/master/core/net/mac/sicslowmac/sicslowmac.c)
but the debug messages are not being printed in packet capture display of
cooja simulator. I have tried using `printf` in every function of `sicslowmac.c`. Also tried `#define DEBUG DEBUG_PRINT` but no success.

I have used sky motes for udp-server.c and udp-client.c in
[rpl-udp](https://github.com/contiki-os/contiki/tree/master/examples/ipv6/rpl-udp). I
am using latest build of contiki. What might I be doing wrong?

I am able to print debug messages from [cc2420.c](https://github.com/contiki-os/contiki/blob/master/dev/cc2420/cc2420.c) and [sicslowpan.c](https://github.com/contiki-os/contiki/blob/master/core/net/ipv6/sicslowpan.c) but not from [sicslowmac.c](https://github.com/contiki-os/contiki/blob/master/core/net/mac/sicslowmac/sicslowmac.c).

P.S: I have not made even a single change to any of the other files. So let not the question be treated as `too broad` or `primarily opinion-based`.

Comment: Have you tried flushing the printf buffer with fflush ?

Comment: @juleslasne: Yes, but no success.

Comment: Try write() from the man 2, it's a sys call, it might help, tell me if it does

Comment: @juleslasne: Thanks a lot for suggesting that.

Comment: Did it work ? I have a printf I re coded myself using write only if you want

Comment: Even if we use write(), sicslowmac.c won't be accessed if we don't set the rdc driver as desired.

Comment: Hooo alright :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got help from contiki mailing list.

We need to tell contiki which RDC driver to use. By default it is [nullrdc_driver](https://github.com/contiki-os/contiki/blob/master/examples/ipv6/rpl-udp/project-conf.h#L51). I changed it to `sicslowmac_driver`.

But then I got `undefined reference to sicslowmac_driver` in `contiki-sky-main.c` of sky platform. I could solve it by adding `core/net/mac/sicslowmac` in Modules of `Makefile.sky`.